# Proguard warning with [java/lang/String]

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm facing issue with proguard. I've some rules in proguard and one of them is:

```
-keep class org.jmrtd.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.jmrtd.**
```

But I've getting this warning when building

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [org/jmrtd/MRTDFileSystem]
  Method      = [readBinary(II)[B]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes) and [org/jmrtd/MRTDFileSystem$MRTDFileInfo] (with 1 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
  Class       = [org/jmrtd/MRTDFileSystem]
  Method      = [readBinary(II)[B]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes) and [org/jmrtd/MRTDFileSystem$MRTDFileInfo] (with 1 known super classes))
```

Can anybody help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you cast return value of `MRTDFileInfo` to a `String` or vice versa at any point? (Basically: show me your code).

Comment: Well, I can't find any usage of this class in project :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a problem with library jar. Are you sure all libraries is configured properly? `MRTDFileInfo` is an inner class of `MRTDFileSystem`, which might be referenced internally.

The processing steps are as follows:

> Input Jar --> Strink --> Optimize --> Obfuscate --> **Preverify** --> output jar

Based on your error trace you are getting an error during the Preverify step: **Unexpected error while preverifying**

If you want to skip this erorr you can simply use prevent Proguard from preverifying:

```
-dontpreverify
```

It will skip preverifying, but I doubt that the jar will run properly

I would suggest you provide your library jars correctly , so that proguard can refer them.

Also apart from -dontwarn , you can also use -ignorewarnings

hope this help in debugging issue.

Comment: Thank you, option -dontpreverify works. Also I checked MRTDFileInfo and it's an inner class of MRTDFileSystem. But your doubts were justified, app not working correctly, but thank you :)

Comment: glad to know current problem is sorted,  I would suggest not to obfuscate library jars, this might solve problem